# Real analysis about open sets in norm metric space

Tags: metric-spaces, normed-spaces

Hi guys I'm having trouble starting this problem..

Consider the metric space $\mathbb R^2$ with the usual, $∥ \cdot ∥$-based metric. Show that, for any real number $r$, the set
$\{(x_1, x_2) \in \mathbb R^2: x_1 + x_2 > r\}$ is open

My professor told me to think about it with $r=0$ but it is still confusing to me. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If $(x_1,x_2)$ is in your set (call it $S$), can you think of a radius size for a ball $B$ centred at $(x_1,x_2)$ such that $B\subset S$?

Answer (score 0):

Say $A=\{(x_1, x_2) \in \mathbb R^2: x_1 + x_2 > r\}$, then $A$ is the whole area above the line $l$ defined by $y=x+r$ (the identity line moved vertically $r$ units.)

Take a point $x=(x_1,x_2)\in A$, then $(x_1,x_2)$ must be above line $l$. Hence $\epsilon = d(x, l) > 0$ (the minimum distance from the point to the line)

Thus, the ball $B_\epsilon(x)$ is above line $l$ and $A$ is open.